# Rails difference between find_by_column vs where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails “find_all_by” vs “.where”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232971/rails-find-all-by-vs-where)

In this piece of code

I was wondering what the difference between line 1 and 2.

The COLUMN_NAME is either nil, or unique value.

```
   def get_row
     id = "someidhere"
1    r = Model.find_by_COLUMN_NAME(id)
2    r = Model.where('COLUMN_NAME = ? ', id).first
     if !r.nil?
     r
     else
       nil
     end
   end
```

Is 2 more explicit than 1? What are some side effects that I should watch out for? (If id was nil, or searching for non existing id)

I was using find_by_COLUMN_NAME before and I was getting **unexpected results**.

When the function returns, I am calling `r.id.to_s` where r should be an instance of Model, however, sometimes I am getting the value `2` from nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.where` methods return an ActiveRecord relation, which means they can be chained with other such methods and scopes, as in `Model.where(:user_id => id).published`. The dynamic finders (`.find_by_name`, etc.), return model instances or arrays, which cannot be chained with additional scopes.

Dynamic finders can return an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error when the expected record is not found (rather than `nil`, `[]`, or an empty relation) if used with an exclamation point, e.g. `User.find_by_email!('example@email.com`)`.

They each have their own uses; it's up to you to decide based on the cases in which your method would be called.