# Why @communities = Community.find_by_author(params[:author]) won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do have a Model called `Community`
I do have a attribute called `author` in communities table.

I do have models/community.rb

However this won't work.  Why?

```
@communities = Community.find_by_author(params[:author])
```

Comment: Model file should be `community.rb`, not `communities.rb`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry about that it's my typo in question.

Comment: find_by_author will return only one record not multiple records. Anyway what u getting in @communities

Comment: Thats how the implementation.. It returns first matching record.

Comment: @MKK Because that's how it works.

Comment: If you want all records user Community.where(:author : params[:author])

Comment: @checkit aha, that's why. Can you show me how to fetch all the records that matches with the same author??

Comment: @checkit thanks:) Could you please post that as answer so that I can vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_by` will give only first matching record. So use `where` to get all matching records.

```
 Community.where(:author => params[:author])
```

Comment: Or `Community.find_all_by_author(params[:author])` (at least it used to work in rails 2.x)

Comment: Is there an incorrect hash syntax? It should be `author: params[:author]` or `:author => params[:author]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You can't use `where` in Rails 2. Thats why we use finder methods. But its better to use `where` when you have. Nice explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232971/rails-find-all-by-vs-where

Comment: @checkit: I am pro-where too. Just, you know, listing all options.