# Rails 4: Fetch Data By Column Name Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to fetch data from db based on some search string. But I am getting the exception

```
undefined method `find_all_by_client_name' for ...
```

Can someone tell what's the issue with the code?

```
@workout_schedules = WorkoutSchedule.find_all_by_client_name(params[:search_string])
```

Following is the schema for workschedule

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140804052924) do

  create_table "workout_schedules", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "client_name"
    t.string   "trainer"
    t.integer  "duration_mins"
    t.date     "date_of_workout"
    t.decimal  "paid_amount"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: paste your `WorkoutSchedule` attributes.. Confirm if column `client_name` really exists

Comment: i have pasted the schema and yes this column exists

Comment: which rails version you are using? Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: rails 4.1.1 is the version i am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4.1, `find_by_<column_name>` and `find_all_by_<column_name>` methods got removed.

In the 4.1 release notes:

> Removed activerecord-deprecated_finders as a dependency. Please see
>   the gem README for more info.

You can achieve the desired result by using `where`:

```
@workout_schedules = WorkoutSchedule.where(:client_name => params[:search_string])
```

I strongly recommend `where` over `find_by`. In attribute based finders imposes extra [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233522/1047207) on your query.

Still if you want to use these finders. You can use **[activerecord-deprecated_finders](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders)** gem to regain the finders feature.

Cheers!

**Edit:**

If you want to search by multiple columns, you can use `where` like this:

```
search_string = params[:search_string]
@workout_schedules = WorkoutSchedule.where(["trainer = ? OR client_name = ?", search_string, search_string])
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot.. can you please tell what if I have to impose multiple condition like OR between trainer and client_name